# How prove this $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{15}<F\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, inequality

> Let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos{nx}}{\sqrt{n^3+n}}$$
>   and $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm dt,F(0)=0$.
>
> ---
>
> 1. Show that: $$\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\dfrac{1}{15}<F\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)<\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
> 2. Find the value $F\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Comment: about (2) is my add it,Thank you @julien

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In the future, instead of making one-character edits, please either take the time to improve the whole post, or just leave it alone for someone else.

Comment: Thank you every much@ThomasAndrews

Comment: I can reduce $F(\pi/2)$ to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{8n^3+2n}}$

Comment: @Lord_Farin Sorry, forgot somebody else might be mid-edit. Hate messed up punctuation. :)

Comment: Thank you,what's meaning? @ratchetfreak

Comment: @ratchetfreak Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Lord_Farin Since you care about edits, what is the point of highlighting the content of the whole post?

Comment: For $(2)$: $f(x)$ looks like a a Fourier Series, if you can find the right function.....

Comment: @julien I do this to mark the part of the question that is the problem statement, usually quoted from some source (quotation, as you probably know, is the primary function of the `>` construct). As it happens, with questions for which the OP shows no work, this means the entire post will end up in a quote.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I understood that. I like the > feature, for its primary purpose as well as for the secondary purpose of highlighting the key points of a post. But in such a case, it looks a little strange to me. Even if the whole post was a quote (which is not, because question 2 was added by the OP).  This is not to criticize your edit, just a thought.

Answer (score 5):

Since the series $f$ converges normally on $\mathbb{R}$, we can integrate term-by-term. This gives
$$
F\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+n}}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos (nx)dx=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{2}(2k+1)^\frac{3}{2}(2k^2+2k+1)^\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
The series converges absolutely to $S$. But this is an alternating series which satisfies Leibniz criterion (the relevant function is [indeed decreasing](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cleft%282x%2b1%5Cright%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5Cleft%282x%5E2%2b2x%2b1%5Cright%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%7D%7D) on $(0,+\infty)$). So the sequence of partial sums $S_n$ alternates about $S$ and satisfies
$$
S_{2n+1}< S< S_{2n} \qquad \forall n\geq 0.
$$
In particular, we get
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{15}<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{5}\sqrt{6}}=S_1<S<S_0=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.
$$
This answers 1.

I don't know if there is a closed form for $S$ and [I am not alone](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28-1%29%5Ek/%28sqrt%282%29%282k%2b1%29%5E%283/2%29%282k%5E2%2b2k%2b1%29%5E%281/2%29%29).

Comment: Thank you,@julien, I think maybe this problem (a) has other nice methos.

Comment: Nice answer (+1).

Comment: My answer adds little to yours (+1), but I also tried to look up the answer on the ISC.

Comment: @math110: which problem has other nice methods, and what might those methods be?

Comment: @robjohn Thanks. And I did not know the ISC...!

Answer (score 0):

I was delayed in posting this, so it is little more than a comment to julien's answer.

Since the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{n^3+n}}$ is convergent, we can integrate term by term
$$
F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{n\sqrt{n^3+n}}
$$
$\sin((2k)\pi/2)=0$ and $\sin((2k+1)\pi/2)=(-1)^k$; therefore,
$$\begin{align}
F(\pi/2)
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{(2k+1)^3(2k^2+2k+1)}}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac1{\sqrt{270}}+\dots
\end{align}
$$
By the alternating series test, the final sum is between $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and $\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac1{\sqrt{270}}$. That is,
$$
\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac1{15}\lt\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac1{\sqrt{270}}\lt F(\pi/2)\lt\frac1{\sqrt2}
$$

This evaluates to $0.6587329279592957$, but the [ISC](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/index) does not find a closed form.